# ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I have the following values, each of which is a scalar of type double: `a1, a2, a3, a4, a5`.

I tried to concatenate them using Numpy, as follows:

```
f = np.concatenate((a1,a2,a3,a4,a5))
```

I however get the following error:

```
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing this weird, convoluted thing instead of `np.array([a1, a2, a3, a4, a5])`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You attempt to use `np.concatenate` incorrectly. And yes, scalars are 0-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Unless the goal of the question is to keep us vigilant and alert on a Friday night...

Comment: @DYZ ROTFL your last comment though ;)

Comment: Sheesh why are people being so snarky. I just had a case where I had a list of np arrays I was concatenating, but in one corner case I ended up with scalars so got this error.

Answer (score 14):

`concatenate` turns each of the items in the list into an array (if it isn't already), and tries to join them:

```
In [129]: np.concatenate([1,2,3,4])
...

ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

`hstack` takes the added step of: `arrs = [atleast_1d(_m) for _m in tup]`, making sure they are at least 1d:

```
In [130]: np.hstack([1,2,3,4])
Out[130]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

But the standard way of creating an array from scalars is with `np.array`, which joins the items along a new axis:

```
In [131]: np.array([1,2,3,4])
Out[131]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Note that `np.array` of 1 scalar is a 0d array:

```
In [132]: np.array(1)
Out[132]: array(1)

In [133]: _.shape
Out[133]: ()
```

If I want to join 4 0d arrays together, how long will that be?  4*0 =0?  4 1d arrays joined on their common axis is 4*1=4; 4 2d arrays (n,m), will be either (4n,m) or (n,4m) depending on the axis.

---

`np.stack` also works.  It does something similar to:

```
In [139]: np.concatenate([np.expand_dims(i,axis=0) for i in [1,2,3,4]])
Out[139]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```