# Creating an array with user input in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to concatenate an array including different element sizes python as an user input
unfortunately it did not work with user input, I got the following error "Value error: Zero-dimensional arrays can not be concatenated"
I do not understand how it works normally but with user input do not work ?

```
 import numpy as np 
 #lst_2=np.concatenate([[1],[2],np.repeat(3,3),[2]])
 lst_2=input("PLEASE ENTER THE THING:: ")

  print('OKKKKL',lst_2)
  np.concatenate(lst_2)
```

Comment: The user input is a string. You need to convert it to an array of numbers so you can concatenate it.

Comment: Zero dimensional arrays means you have not instantiated the array. You cannot concat without declaring a new/existing array. Also this seems like a common question so try to search for similar answers. [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471329/valueerror-zero-dimensional-arrays-cannot-be-concatenated)

Comment: You printed `lst_2`.  What did it show?  The argument to `np.concatenate` much be a list of arrays (or something like that).  Also beware, `concatenate` does not operate in-place.  Take more time to examine your variables, and to read the function docs.

Comment: @hpaulj
Thank you for your answer, 
My question how when I defined it and typed it , it worked, 
however, now it's not working with user input ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, in more detail, you create a list:

```
In [251]: alist = [[1],[2],np.repeat(3,3),[2]]
In [252]: alist
Out[252]: [[1], [2], array([3, 3, 3]), [2]]
```

and apply `concatenate` to that list:

```
In [253]: np.concatenate(alist)
Out[253]: array([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2])
```

With `input`, if I copy-n-paste the same thing, I get a `string`:

```
In [254]: astr = input()
[[1],[2],np.repeat(3,3),[2]]
In [255]: astr
Out[255]: '[[1],[2],np.repeat(3,3),[2]]'
```

The quotes are important.  `concatenate` does not work with that:

```
In [256]: np.concatenate(astr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-256-95017eec7f88>", line 1, in <module>
    np.concatenate(astr)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

The string has to be converted to a list first:

```
In [257]: alist1 = eval(astr)    # better ast.literal_eval
In [258]: alist1
Out[258]: [[1], [2], array([3, 3, 3]), [2]]
In [259]: np.concatenate(alist1)
Out[259]: array([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2])
```

Entering strings as code is different from entering them via the `input` function.

Comment: Thank you, got it!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all the input will be taken as a string. You need to take that string and convert it to a list. This is achieved by splitting it with respect to a separator. Finally just use the `np.array` to create an array from a list. `np.concatenate` is used to put together objects that are already arrays.

```py
import numpy as np 

raw_input=input("PLEASE ENTER THE THING:: ")

# here i use space, but anything can be the separator
input_list = raw_input.split(" ") 

# dtype is optional, but unless you specify it, it will be `string`
arr = np.array(input_list, dtype=int)
```

##### UPDATE:

If you want repeating elements, as you said, you could give pairs of numbers, as inputs, like this:

```py
import numpy as np 

user_input = input("PLEASE ENTER THE THING:: ")
input_list = user_input.split(",") 
print(input_list)
arr = np.concatenate(
    [np.repeat(int(pair.split(' ')[0]), 
               int(pair.split(' ')[1])) 
    for pair in input_list]
)

print(arr)
# example input: 1 10,2 3,4 4
# output [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 4]
```

here you have pairs separated by "," and the numbers in each pair are separated by a space. This script will repeat the first number in the pair as many times as the second number specifies. In order for this to work make sure you don't add a space after the comma when you input numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

Sounds ok, but what if I wanna repeat an element for 15 times or so ??
Anyway 
in array I could type: np.repeat(3,15)

Answer (score 0):

the `input()` function always returns a string. If your input is like `1234`, you have to write: `lst_2=input("PLEASE ENTER THE THING:: ").split('')`